# Как сделать так, чтобы бот смог повторять(редактировать) одно и тоже сообщение каждую секунду

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы бот смог каждую секунду редактирует одно и тоже сообщение.
Например: таймер или же секундомер в чате дискорда.

```
@bot.command()
async def DR(ctx):
    await ctx.send('текст')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def DR(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('текст')
    counter = 0
    while counter != 5:
        counter += 1
        await msg.edit(content='текст2')
        import asyncio
        asyncio.sleep(5) # timeout, меньше 5 минут не следует ставить, так как может сработать рейт лимит
```

Comment: Как исправить **TypeError: Message.edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**